# GPG signing failure

Tags: gpg

Running the commands

```bash
export GPG_TTY=$(tty) 
git commit -S -m "message"
```

is resulting in failure to sign the key as the pin entry is still opening in the pop up window. Unusually this was working until Monday.

Error message:

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data:
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 083911F97A0F391067ECEEC24CD24B8702F76476 2
[GNUPG:] BEGIN_SIGNING H10
[GNUPG:] PINENTRY_LAUNCHED 2512429 gnome3 1.2.1 /dev/pts/5 xterm-256color :1 20620/1000/5 1000/1000 -
```

I have tried resetting the gpg-agent with no success. (running Ubuntu 23.10)